# full calendar throwing error when going to the calendar page second time

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar plugin provided by http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/. 
I am loading the fullcalendar.js file only once in my website. The first time when i go to calendar view i get the events correctly. when i navigate to another page and come back i am getting following exception
Caught[via 'error' event]:  'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' from 
So i want to explore it further and debugged into the fullcalendar.js and found that the exception was due to the formatDates(date1,date2,format,options) function in fullcalendar.js. I found that the format was undefined when i come to the calendar page second time. But i found that the function that is calling this formatDates was passing the right format. can any one please help me how to solve this. I am new to fullcalendar plugin.

Comment: Seems like a Var that is not being populated when you come back...Can you provide a JsFiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error.
Solution for me - I remove 
    "timeFormat: { // for event elements
      //        '': 'h(:mm)t' // default
      '': 'HH(:mm)' // default
    }," 
from velocity (but in fullcalendar.js timeFormat remained).